# Android Studio Layout Change Errors

Tags: android-layout

When i change the the the layout from "android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1" to    "R.layout.row_layout" i get a "Unfortunatly ... has stopped"

layout file: row_layout.xml

```
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context="com1032.cw1.sd00465.sd00465_todolist.MainActivity">

   <TextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:id="@+id/text2"
    />
```

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String[] Alrams = {"Alarm 1", "Alarm 2", "Alarm 3", "Alarm 4", "Alarm 5"};

    ListAdapter theAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, *android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1*, Alrams);
    ListView theListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.List1);
    theListView.setAdapter(theAdapter);


}
```

Code which fails:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String[] Alrams = {"Alarm 1", "Alarm 2", "Alarm 3", "Alarm 4", "Alarm 5"};

    ListAdapter theAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, *R.layout.row_layout*, Alrams);
    ListView theListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.List1);
    theListView.setAdapter(theAdapter);


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out what was causing the error, managed to reproduce what you were encountering. Here are the logs:

```
03-11 09:58:34.925 15382-15382/com.example.aalawi.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                  Process: com.example.aalawi.myapplication, PID: 15382
                                                                                  java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
                                                                                      at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:386)
                                                                                      at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
                                                                                      at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2347)
                                                                                      at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1864)
                                                                                      at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:698)
                                                                                      at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:759)
                                                                                      at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1673)
                                                                                      at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2151)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
                                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
                                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
                                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
                                                                                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
                                                                                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
                                                                                      at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:435)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
                                                                                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
                                                                                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
                                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
                                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
                                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
                                                                                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
                                                                                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2086)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1843)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1061)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5885)
                                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
                                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
                                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
                                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
                                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
```

This was caused by the `row_layout.xml`, based on the code you provided, the TextView itself is inside another Layout. The ArrayAdapter class, according to the Android Developers Site -- [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter(android.content.Context, int, T[])) --

> resource  int: The resource ID for a layout file containing a TextView
>   to use when instantiating views.

So the solution is for you to remove the parent layout of the `TextView` in the `row_layout.xml`. Just make it as a `TextView`, like so.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</TextView>
```

Let me know if it works. :) Happy coding. :)

Comment: Thanks. Worked perfectly